# Create a long data frame comprising number sequences according to each user's value in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Assume I have a data frame like:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"user_id": [1, 5, 11],
                   "user_type": ["I", "I", "II"],
                   "joined_for": [1.4, 9.4, 18.1]})
```

Now I'd like to:

1. Take each user's `joined_for` and get the ceiling integer.
2. Based on the integer, create a new data frame containing number sequences where the maximum is the ceiling number.

This is how I do it now:

```
import math
new_df = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(df.shape[0]):
    ceil_num = math.ceil(df.iloc[i]["joined_for"])
    new_df = new_df.append(pd.DataFrame({"user_id": df.iloc[i]["user_id"],
                                         "joined_month": range(1, ceil_num+1)}),
                           ignore_index=True)
new_df = new_df.merge(df.drop(columns="joined_for"), on="user_id")
```

`new_df` is what I want, but it's so time-consuming when there are lots of users and the number of `joined_for` can be larger. Is there any better way to do this? Faster or neater?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a comprehension

```
pd.DataFrame([
    [t.user_id, m, t.user_type] for t in df.itertuples(index=False)
    for m in range(1, math.ceil(t.joined_for) + 1)
], columns=['user_id', 'joined_month', 'user_type'])

    user_id  joined_month user_type
0         1             1         I
1         1             2         I
2         5             1         I
3         5             2         I
4         5             3         I
5         5             4         I
6         5             5         I
7         5             6         I
8         5             7         I
9         5             8         I
10        5             9         I
11        5            10         I
12       11             1        II
13       11             2        II
14       11             3        II
15       11             4        II
16       11             5        II
17       11             6        II
18       11             7        II
19       11             8        II
20       11             9        II
21       11            10        II
22       11            11        II
23       11            12        II
24       11            13        II
25       11            14        II
26       11            15        II
27       11            16        II
28       11            17        II
29       11            18        II
30       11            19        II
```